# C# Debug Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, debugging

Is there an attribute I can specify on a method so that when I am debugging the debugger knows to step inside of a method?  I am overriding a Databind() method and currently the debugger steps over it automatically.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but have you tried DebuggableAttribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.aspx

Comment: Did the class get built with a [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute on it?

Answer (score 4):

Just put a breakpoint inside the method you wish to debug.

If the breakpoint isn't hit when debugging, that would mean the method is not being called - are you sure you have overriden it correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it will break if the method or class has DebuggerStepThrough attached to it?

Comment: @Rune FS - Of course, if the method itself is so decorated, the breakpoint will not be hit. However, this is hardly likely the case, from reading the question. If the OP had overridden the method and decorated it with `DebuggerStepThrough` then he would be answering his own question. As for it being defined on the method being overridden - the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute has a `Inherited = false` set in its `AttributeUsage`, so this can also be ruled out.

Comment: agreed but that still leaves the class usage. (I do however agree with you that it's unlikely to be the case)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers guys, no one came up with what I was looking for though. I knew I had seen this before so I just did some more searching and found it again.  There are several debugging attributes that live in System.Diagnostics, the ones I were looking for were DebuggerStepThrough() and DebuggerHidden().

```
    // Force the debugger to step through this code
    [DebuggerStepThrough()]
    public double GrandTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.Subtotal + this.Tax + this.Shipping);
        }
    }
```

And...

```
    // Force the debugger to skip step through
    [DebuggerHidden()]
    public double GrandTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.Subtotal + this.Tax + this.Shipping);
        }
    }
```

Edit: Oded you posted a comment about this above, this is actually what I was looking for :)  I would have selected this as an answer but you did not post it as an answer?

Comment: This explanation is misleading, `DebuggerStepThrough` will _**prevent** the debugger from stepping into your method_, `DebuggerHidden` on the other hand will also prevent the debugger from stepping into your code _and_ will not show the method at all in the stack trace!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Oded's answer but another option is use [Debugger.Break()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx). This will cause your code to break every time it hits that line of code if the debugger is attached.

Answer (score 0):

What version of VS are you using? One thing that might be helpful, under Tools|Options, "Debugging node: Enable Just My Code (Managed only)" – clear, "Enable .NET Framework source Stepping" – set.

Do you have a breakpoint set in your override?